# mysql query from 5 table

Tags: mysql

I try this query, but error

```
SELECT e.productcode, e.productname,
       COALESCE(p.TotalPur, 0) TotalPur,
       COALESCE(rp.rpQty, 0) rpQty,
       COALESCE(s.TotalSold, 0) TotalSold,
       COALESCE(rs.rsQty, 0) rsQty,
       COALESCE(p.TotalPur, 0) - COALESCE(rp.rpQty, 0) AS purQty,
       COALESCE(s.TotalSold, 0) - COALESCE(rs.rsQty, 0) AS saleQty,
       COALESCE(purQty, 0) - COALESCE(saleQty, 0) AvQty
FROM productmaster e
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT productcode, SUM(qty) TotalSold
                FROM saledetail
                GROUP BY productcode) s
     ON e.productcode = s.productcode
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT productcode, SUM(qty) rpQty
                FROM purdetailreturn
                GROUP BY productcode) rp
     ON e.productcode=rp.productcode
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT productcode, SUM(qty) rsQty
                FROM saledetailreturn
                GROUP BY productcode) rs
     ON e.productcode=rs.productcode
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT productcode, SUM(qty) TotalPur
                FROM purdetail
                GROUP BY productcode) p
     ON e.productcode = p.productcode;
```

Comment: Please, post the error message.

Comment: For other people to help you, you should add all the relevant information. At least, you should point out which is the *error returned by MySQL*. In most cases, it is also necessary that you send the definitions of all *tables* (and views) involved in your query.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a renamed column at the same level since the alias is not known at the time for evaluation of the expression. Either add a level of nesting:

```
SELECT productcode, productname, TotalPur, rpQty, TotalSold
    ,  rsQty, purQty, saleQty, (purQty - saleQty) AvQty
FROM
(  SELECT e.productcode, e.productname,
       COALESCE(p.TotalPur, 0) TotalPur,
       COALESCE(rp.rpQty, 0) rpQty,
       COALESCE(s.TotalSold, 0) TotalSold,
       COALESCE(rs.rsQty, 0) rsQty,
       COALESCE(p.TotalPur, 0) - COALESCE(rp.rpQty, 0) AS purQty,
       COALESCE(s.TotalSold, 0) - COALESCE(rs.rsQty, 0) AS saleQty,
   FROM ...
   ...
) T;
```

Note that you don't need COALESCE for `AvQty` since both `purQty` and `saleQty` is guaranteed to have a value.

or duplicate the expressions:

```
SELECT e.productcode, e.productname,
   COALESCE(p.TotalPur, 0) TotalPur,
   COALESCE(rp.rpQty, 0) rpQty,
   COALESCE(s.TotalSold, 0) TotalSold,
   COALESCE(rs.rsQty, 0) rsQty,
   COALESCE(p.TotalPur, 0) - COALESCE(rp.rpQty, 0) AS purQty,
   COALESCE(s.TotalSold, 0) - COALESCE(rs.rsQty, 0) AS saleQty,
   COALESCE(p.TotalPur, 0) - COALESCE(rp.rpQty, 0) - COALESCE(s.TotalSold, 0) + COALESCE(rs.rsQty, 0) AS AvQty       
FROM ...
```